# Upstream messaging in Android Studio using Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) module with Google App Engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to make use of the 'Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)' in my Android application project. Specifically, I'm working on making the 'backend' with the Google App Engine(GAE) and have added the Google Cloud Messaging Module to my Android Studio project.

I've had success with following the tutorial on Github(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints). The downstream messaging is working like a charm.

However, I couldn't get the *upstream messaging* to work.

[EDIT]
I've managed to make a VPS(Virtual Personal Server) with the google cloud's compute engine and have installed an apache server on it.

I have read from the google cloud documentation that I should write some serverside code so that I can retrieve the information on the cloud/server side and process it, probably to simply echo what the user sends via upstream gcm.

Being new to servers, I'm not sure what I should do... I think I'm lost. I'd really appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream has the snippet explained. With correct amount of details, I don't know, depends reader.

Comment: are you using XMPP protocol configured on your server receiving Upstream msgs?

Comment: I've made a server, yes, but not an XMPP server... Do I have to install an XMPP server? for example, Openfire?

Comment: yes you need to configure the XMPP server @ChanheeJeong